# share content from mobile app in flex

Tags: apache-flex, share

I am developing a mobile app using flex 4.5

I want to let the user share a plain text using any of the apps available in his device (whatsapp, facebook, skype, bluetooth, ..). How can I do that? I know how to email, sms and call. But don't know how to share.

Please help

Comment: You need an ANE, for example http://myappsnippet.com/adobe-air-share-extension/ and there are probably more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Air does not have native support for this feature, however you can use it with the navigateToURL method, but its still very clumsy.

You need to use Android SDK Share Intent URL's to access the native share menu's.
more info here: [Air Share Intent](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/891366)

Comment: thanx! but still not clear how I can pass the body of the message to be shared inside the url. any hint?